# How to get seekbar default progress position on activity created

Tags: android, android-seekbar

I have the following code in `onCreate()` Activity:

```
SeekBar vSeekbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
final TextView tvText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
//sets seekbar tab position from a randomly generated number...
//when the acitivty is first created I would like the SeekBar position to be set in the `textView`
tvText.setText(vSeekbar.getProgress()); //this is not showing anything...

//the onchangelistener works correctly...
vSeekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress, boolean arg2)
    {
        tvText.setText(String.valueOf(progress)); //this works fine...
    }
});
```

The `seekBar1` position is set by a random number generated when the view is created so no way for me to know beforehand.

How can I get the `seekBar1` position when the view is created and set it in the `textView`.

Comment: use  seekbar.setProgress(5); and then try to get value of seekbar

Answer (score 2):

After random value set to seekbar call vSeekbar.getProgress() method. before you called then only you got zero value.

```
vSeekbar.setProgress(randomValue());
tvText.setText(vSeekbar.getProgress()+"");
```

Comment: This will most likely throw a `Resources$NotFoundException`.

Comment: sry @MikeM I am not understand can you tell clearly.

Comment: The `TextView#setText()` overload that takes an `int` argument is for setting the text to a Resource String. It is highly unlikely that `SeekBar#getProgress()` will return a valid String Resource identifier, in which case it will throw that Exception.

Answer (score 0):

You better limit your random values to the `ProgressBar` maximum value.

For example if your maximum value is 100 then use the following code: `vSeekbar.setProgress(randomValue() % 100);`

It will limit the random values to 0 to 99